# procedure Get (Item : out String); ( in a Function)

Tags: string, function, ada

I'm trying to return a global variable's String value , and want to use the function who use it , later in a procedure .

```
function get_name return String
is begin
Put_line("Your name?");
 Get(name); -- name is in "globals"
 put(name);
return name;
end get_name;
```

The package file =

```
package globals
is
name : String(1..20) ;
end globals;
```

Here the "Get" which is used in the function =

```
       procedure Get (Item : out String);
```

Now , if i use the fonction in a procedure , it compile but =

At launching , no get is executing , the program "create" a "skip" line !!?

So , is it possible to use this procedure Get in a function ??

And how do you call the function who contain it , after ??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you call the procedure `Get(Item : out String)`, then the number of characters you read will have to be exactly 20 characters.

If you want to use the function `get`, you'll need to initialise a variable with its value, or pass it through as a parameter. e.g.

```
x : string := get_line; -- functional version that will read an entire line
```

or

```
put(get_line); -- read and entire line, pass it immediately to a procedure
```

As to why your input is skipping over the get, and not reading anything, this is probably because you have previously read some input, and have left a newline/end of line marker in the input. This happens often if you read numbers.

e.g. input is

```
34\nThe next line\n
```

If you read an integer, the file pointer will show you are at...

```
34\nThe next line\n
..^
```

Then you ask for a `get_line`, and you'll end up only reading to the end of the line (where you currently are) and you'll have a empty string, and not have read the next line.

The solution is to have a `skip_line` after each get.
So

```
get(number); skip_line;

declare 
   input : string := get_line;
begin
   ...
```

Comment: Thanks , and just with get , i finally succeed :)